# Embedded video playing with multiple orientations?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, uiwebview, html5-video

I want to play dailymotion and youtube videos in my UIWebView control. And I'm using following embedded html code to play and it's working fine. But as device is being rotate, it's not resetting accordingly and if I call the following code again it will start to play video from beginning.

```
    NSString* embedHTML = @"<html><head><style>body {\"background-color:transparent;color:black;\"}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"width=\"%.0f\" height=\"%.0f\"></embed></body></html>";
    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
```

Any solution that reset my view according to the device rotation and continue playing without restarting..?

**EDIT:**
Video is changing orientation perfectly in playing mode. Once I have stopped it and trying to rotate view, the webview's content does not rotating. And I am looking for the solution of that.

Answer (score 0):

I had made a tutorial for this and where it is working with interface orienatation changes also.

Here is the implementation file. Just copy paste into your controller,put your URL and try this code

```
 #import "TestVideoViewController.h"
 #import "UICommonUtils.h"

@implementation TestVideoViewController
@synthesize TestVideoView;


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //sleep(10.0);
    [busyLoadingView hide:YES];
    //bShow = NO;
} 

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //sleep(10.0);
    [busyLoadingView hide:YES];
    //bShow = NO;
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
     //bShow = YES;
     //[busyLoadingView showWhileExecuting:@selector(showCursor:) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

     //[busyLoadingView show:YES];
     return YES;
}

 - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [busyLoadingView show:YES];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self embedVideo1:@"PASS HERE URL1" andVideo2:@"PASS HERE URL2" frame:self.view.frame];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rectFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;

    self.view.frame = rectFrame;
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    //TestVideoView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
//TestVideoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    busyLoadingView = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];


    // Add HUD to screen
    [self.view addSubview:busyLoadingView];

    busyLoadingView.labelText = @"Loading...";

    [self embedVideo1:@"PASS HERE URL1" andVideo2:@"PASS HERE URL2" frame:self.view.frame];

    //self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    //self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

}

- (void)embedVideo1:(NSString*)url1 andVideo2:(NSString*)url2 frame:(CGRect)frame {  
        float videoWidth = 748.0;
    float videoHeight = 341.0;
    //int marginLeft = 10;
    //int marginTop = 10;

    if ([UICommonUtils isiPad]){
        videoWidth = 748.0;
        videoHeight = 341.0;
        //marginLeft = (int)(frame.size.width - videoWidth) /2;
        //marginTop = 10;
    } else {
        videoWidth = 300.0;
        videoHeight = 160.0;
        //marginLeft = 10;
        //marginTop = 10;
    }

    NSString* embedHTML = @" \
         <html><head> \
     <style type=\"text/css\"> \
     .style11 { \
     font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; \
     font-weight:bold; \
     font-size:16; \
    } \
     .style12 { \
     width: \"%0.0f\"; \
     height=\"%0.0f\" \
     align = center; \
     } \
     .style21 { \
     font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; \
     font-weight:bold; \
     font-size:16; \
     } \
     .style22 { \
     width: \"%0.0f\"; \
     height=\"%0.0f\" \
     align = center; \
     } \
     body {\
     background-color: transparent; \
     color: black; \
     } \
    </style> \
    </head><body> \
    <table> \
    <tr><td><span class=\"style11\">1) Collecting and Editing Leads</span></td></tr> \
    <tr><td height=20></td></tr> \
    <tr><td class=\"style12\"> \
    <embed id=\"yt1\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\">  \
        </embed> \
    </td></tr> \
    <tr height=20></tr> \
    <tr><td><span class=\"style21\">2) Accessing Leads Online</span></td></tr> \
    <tr><td height=20></td></tr> \
    <tr><td class=\"style22\"> \
    <embed id=\"yt2\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\">  \
    </embed> \
    </td></tr> \
    </table> \
       </body></html>";  
    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, videoWidth, videoHeight, videoWidth, videoHeight, url1, videoWidth, videoHeight, url2, \
                  videoWidth, videoHeight];  
    //NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, videoWidth, videoHeight, videoWidth, videoHeight, url1, videoWidth-20, videoHeight, url2, \
    //                videoWidth-20, videoHeight];   
   /*
    if(videoView == nil) {  
        videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];  
        [self.view addSubview:videoView];  
    } */ 
    //[TestVideoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];  
    [(UIWebView *)self.view loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];  
}  


 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     // Return YES for supported orientations
     //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 //return YES;
    if([UICommonUtils isiPad]) return YES;
    else return NO;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    //CGRect rectFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;

    //self.view.frame = rectFrame;
    //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"origin x: %f origin y: %f width: %f height: %f", rectFrame.origin.x,
    //     rectFrame.origin.y, rectFrame.size.width, rectFrame.size.height]);

    //TestVideoView.frame = CGRectMake(rectFrame.origin.x, rectFrame.origin.y, rectFrame.size.height, rectFrame.size.width);    
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

     // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
     [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Here is the header file for the ViewController

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "MBProgressHUD.h"


 @interface TestVideoViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>{
    UIWebView *TestVideoView;
    MBProgressHUD *busyLoadingView;
    BOOL bShow;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *TestVideoView;

- (void)embedVideo1:(NSString*)url1 andVideo2:(NSString*)url2 frame:(CGRect)frame;

@end
```

Hope this helps you.

If you require more help then please let me know.

**EDIT: 
This code most probably wont work properly on simulator as simulator doesnt have a shockwave- flash player**

Comment: The compiler shows error for #import "UICommonUtils.h". #import "UICommonUtils.h" has been missing. Kindly let me know the reference for the class.

Comment: no it was my custom class to check whether device is iphone or ipad. Right now you can consider playing it on ipad device if you have or iphone device in that case so that you dont have to check the device type. So you can remove the conditional check and reference to UICommonUtils class.

Comment: Check the edit section of my answer as well.. I have added an important point over there as well though it has nothing to do with your UICommonUtils class error

Comment: As I have to play a single video, I have omit andVideo2:(NSString*)url2. Does that make any problem?

Comment: No that won't create any problem. that is fine

Comment: My code is already woking but the problem is somewhat different. Please check my updated question

Comment: @iApple: My solution works perfectly fine in all the conditions. So please check it out in detail

Comment: I am not commenting anything wrong to your code, but the same thing is done with my 2 lines code, that I have given. So thanks for your help but sorry to say that it is not the solution for what I'm looking for. Hope you are getting me in right way..!

Comment: Ok fine. I thought to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate the following code:
http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/embedding-youtube-within-iphone-apps/