# How to re-set the height & width of embedded player using CSS?

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad

I want to create a couple of CSS to manage the orientation of embedded video player in UIWebView. And these CSS shall work to resize the player according to the device's orientation.

How can I create and add a CSS in my iphone application to execute the following code with my iPhone/iPad?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```

**EDIT:**

Following is the code that I have done for embedded video.(*youTubePlayer is an instance of UIWebView.)

```
    NSString* embedHTML = @"<html><head><style=\"margin:0\" link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all and (orientation:portrait)\" href=\"portrait.css\">"
    "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all and (orientation:landscape)\" href=\"landscape.css\">"
    "</style></head>"
    "<body embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"></embed>"
    "</body></html>";
    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [youTubePlayer loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

And also have added **landscape.css**
        body
        {
            width: 1002;
            height: 768;
        }

**portrait.css**
        body
        {
            width: 768;
            height: 1024;
        }

Even though it's not working properly. What is wrong with the code, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have reached to my destination and sort out the problem by the following code. It's working perfect with youtube videos and also setting orientation of UIWebview. The benefit of the following code is, it won't re-start the video on the change of orientation of device.

```
    NSString* embedHTML = @"<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all and (orientation:portrait)\" href=\"portrait-ipad.css\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all and (orientation:landscape)\" href=\"landscape-ipad.css\"></head><body><iframe type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></body></html>";
    NSString *videoID = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" withString:@""];
    videoID = [videoID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&feature=youtube_gdata" withString:@""];
    html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, videoID];      
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [youTubePlayer loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

(youTubePlayer is an instance of UIWebView.)

Answer (score 0):

are you just missing px after your widths and heights? eg portrait.css body { width: 768px; height: 1024px; } instead of portrait.css body { width: 768; height: 1024; }

Comment: 'px' doesn't make difference to implement the css effect.